# print list like a table of 3 columns

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing, python-class

Is there a way to make the list (self.produits) look like a table ?

```py
class Stock :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.produits=[]
    def ajouter_produit(self,nom,puht,qt):
        self.produits.append(nom)
        self.produits.append(puht)
        self.produits.append(qt)
    def saisir(self,n):
        for i in range(n):
            nom,puht,qt=produit.saisir_produit()
            self.ajouter_produit(nom,puht,qt)
    def afficher(self):
        print("NOM     |PUHT    |QUANTITE")
        print (self.produits)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCyeS.png)

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ywK.png)

Comment: What code are you running to get your current output?

Comment: `s=Stock()
s.saisir(4)
s.afficher()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def afficher(self):
    start = 0
    end = len(self.produits)
    step = 3
    print("NOM     |PUHT    |QUANTITE")
    for i in range(start, end, step):
        print("{:<8}|{:<8}|{}".format(self.produits[i],self.produits[i+1],self.produits[i+2]))
```